# running junit form command line: initializationError(SLLTest): No runnable methods

Tags: java, junit, command-line

I am trying to execute Junit test using Powershell script. But I keep getting initializationError(SLLTest): No runnable methods

The same test cases run fine from eclipse. I am also overriding the classpath to use the same jars eclipse uses during both compilation and execution.

// TestRunner

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class TestRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    PrintStream original = System.out;
    Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestSuite.class);
    System.setOut(original);
    for(Failure failure : result.getFailures())
        System.out.println(failure);
    if(result.wasSuccessful())
        System.out.println("Success");

}

}
```

// one of the test classes

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

public class StackQTest{
StackQ s = new StackQ();

@Test
public void pushPopTest() {
    s.push(1);
    s.push(2);
    s.push(3);
    s.push(4);
    s.push(5);
    assertEquals(5, s.pop());
    assertEquals(4, s.pop());
    assertEquals(3, s.pop());
    assertEquals(2, s.pop());
    assertEquals(1, s.pop());
}
}
```

// test suite class

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;
import org.junit.runners.Suite.SuiteClasses;

@RunWith (Suite.class)
@SuiteClasses ({SLLTest.class, DLLTest.class, RecursionTest.class,
QueueSTest.class, StackQTest.class})
public class TestSuite {

}
```

I am expecting "Success" as an output put I always get:

```
initializationError(SLLTest): No runnable methods
initializationError(DLLTest): No runnable methods 
initializationError(RecursionTest): No runnable methods
initializationError(QueueSTest): No runnable methods
initializationError(StackQTest): No runnable methods
```

Comment: Which jUnit version are you using? In some version test methods should start with `test` like `testPushPop()`

Comment: @Ivan I am using JUnit 5. I tried using the format you mentioned. the result is the same